# Initialization of the structure

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, initialization

In my program I have structure:

```
struct point {

  float x;
  float y;

};
```

Edit: I need to create

```
   struct Path{
   Point array[];
}
```

Initialize it with function `init_path(Path *p, int size)`.
My question is, how to define the function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking about. Improve your question please! What is `init_path()`  supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Path` may be like:

```
struct Path {
    point* points;
};

void init_path(Path *path, int size) {
    path->points = new point[size]();
}
```

but why your professor wants a function instead of proper constructor/destructor remains a mystery. Here you still need to call `delete[]` on `points` somewhere. With following structure you don't need any `init` function and object will properly delete its resources.

```
struct Path {
    Path(unsigned size) : points{ new point[size] } {}
    ~Path() { delete[] points; }
    point* points;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I though about it. But not sure why he told us to define Path as array of points, not a pointer. Anyway, thanks! You confirmed that this is the easiest way ;)